# Drop all rows before first occurrence of a value

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a df like so:

```
Year  ID Count
1997  1  0
1998  2  0
1999  3  1
2000  4  0
2001  5  1
```

and I want to remove all rows before the first occurrence of `1` in `Count` which would give me:

```
Year  ID Count
1999  3  1
2000  4  0
2001  5  1
```

I can remove all rows AFTER the first occurrence like this:

```
df=df.loc[: df[(df['Count'] == 1)].index[0], :]
```

but I can't seem to follow the slicing logic to make it do the opposite.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd do:

```
df[(df.Count == 1).idxmax():]
```

[image]

---

`df.Count == 1` returns a boolean array.  `idxmax()` will identify the index of the maximum value.  I know the max value will be `True` and when there are more than one `True`s it will return the position of the first one found.  That's exactly what you want.  By the way, that value is `2`.  Finally, I slice the dataframe for everything from `2` onward with `df[2:]`.  I put all that in one line in the answer above.

Answer (score 5):

you can use [cumsum()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) method:

```
In [13]: df[(df.Count == 1).cumsum() > 0]
Out[13]:
   Year  ID  Count
2  1999   3      1
3  2000   4      0
4  2001   5      1
```

Explanation:

```
In [14]: (df.Count == 1).cumsum()
Out[14]:
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    2
Name: Count, dtype: int32
```

**Timing** against 500K rows DF:

```
In [18]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [19]: df.shape
Out[19]: (500000, 3)

In [20]: %timeit df[(df.Count == 1).idxmax():]
100 loops, best of 3: 3.7 ms per loop

In [21]: %timeit df[(df.Count == 1).cumsum() > 0]
100 loops, best of 3: 16.4 ms per loop

In [22]: %timeit df.loc[df[(df['Count'] == 1)].index[0]:, :]
The slowest run took 4.01 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100 loops, best of 3: 7.02 ms per loop
```

Conclusion: @piRSquared's `idxmax()` solution is a clear winner...

Answer (score 4):

Using [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df[np.where(df['Count']==1)[0][0]:]
```

**Timings**

Timings were performed on a larger version of the DataFrame:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10**5, ignore_index=True)
```

Results:

```
%timeit df[np.where(df['Count']==1)[0][0]:]  
100 loops, best of 3: 2.74 ms per loop

%timeit df[(df.Count == 1).idxmax():] 
100 loops, best of 3: 6.18 ms per loop

%timeit df[(df.Count == 1).cumsum() > 0] 
10 loops, best of 3: 26.6 ms per loop

%timeit df.loc[df[(df['Count'] == 1)].index[0]:, :]
100 loops, best of 3: 11.2 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Just slice the other way :

if idx is your index do :

```
df.loc[idx:]
```

Instead of

```
df.loc[:idx]
```

That means :

```
df.loc[df[(df['Count'] == 1)].index[0]:, :]
```