# Keep all rows before first occurrence of a value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and the opposite question to [Drop all rows before first occurrence of a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38707165/drop-all-rows-before-first-occurrence-of-a-value)

Instead of drop all rows before the first occurence of a value, I want to keep the rows before the first occurence of a value. so for example, i want to keep all the rows before the occurence `1` in the column count:

```
Year  ID Count
1997  1  0
1998  2  0
1999  3  1
2000  4  0
2001  5  1
```

leads to:

```
Year  ID Count
1997  1  0
1998  2  0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html) and negate its output (`~`) to form a boolean Series for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df[~df['Count'].eq(1).cummax()]
```

Output:

```
   Year  ID  Count
0  1997   1      0
1  1998   2      0
```

Intermediates:

```
   Year  ID  Count  eq(1)  cummax      ~
0  1997   1      0  False   False   True
1  1998   2      0  False   False   True
2  1999   3      1   True    True  False
3  2000   4      0  False    True  False
4  2001   5      1   True    True  False
```

Variant, if you are sure that there is at least one `1`:

```
out = df.iloc[:np.argmax(df['Count'].eq(1))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution (I have just noticed that it is similar to @mozway's second solution). This solution also works when there is no `1`. It also works with no standard index.

```
m = df['Count'].eq(1)

df if ~m.any() else df.iloc[:m.idxmax()]
```

Output:

```
   Year  ID  Count
0  1997   1      0
1  1998   2      0
```

Comment: Two notes, `idxmax`/`argmax` only works if you have one match (else this will match the first row and produce an empty DataFrame). `idxmax`+`iloc` won't work if you don't have a standard range index (which is why I went with `np.argmax`, you could also `reset_index`+`idxmax`) ;)

Comment: Thanks, @mozway, for commenting my solution. Regarding your first note, that is true, but I think I can fix that even keeping `idxmax`. Concerning your second note, I have tried with the non-regular index `4, 3, 2, 1, 0` and it seems to work fine.

Comment: I have just edited my solution accordingly, @mozway.